# Getting SSL error while sending email, can't connect to Postfix

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, postfix-mta, nodemailer

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  host: 'mail.mydomain.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'hello',
    pass: 'thepassword'
  }
}));

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'Tester <test@mydomain.com>', // sender address
  to: 'someemail@gmail.com', // list of receivers
  subject: 'Hello', // Subject line
  text: 'hey', // plaintext body
  html: 'hey' // html body
};

transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

I am trying to connect to my own postfix server to send an email via SMTP. However, when I run this, I get:

```
[Error: 139969407567744:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:787: ]
```

I'm certain that my SMTP port is 587. I'm certain that I have SSL enabled on my Postfix server. I connect through SSL from my Mail app on the Mac.

This is my postfix config:

```
myhostname = mail.mydomain.com
myorigin = mail.mydomain.com
mydestination = mail.mydomain.com, mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, regexp:/etc/aliases_regex
#alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

smtpd_tls_CAfile=/etc/postfix/tls/startssl-ca-bundle.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/tls/mail.mydomain.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/tls/mail.mydomain.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes


smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

#local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891

virtual_alias_domains =mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

I'm using StartSSL for my Postfix sever. And on my Node.js server, I see this:

```
StartCom_Certification_Authority_2.pem
StartCom_Certification_Authority_G2.pem
StartCom_Certification_Authority.pem
```

in `/etc/ssl`.  So, I am assuming that my Node.js server has the root certificates already installed.

When I run the Node.js code above, I get this on my `mail.log`:

```
Sep 13 04:08:30 d-mail postfix/submission/smtpd[724]: connect from unknown[107.170.206.11]
Sep 13 04:08:30 d-mail postfix/submission/smtpd[724]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from unknown[107.170.206.11]
Sep 13 04:08:30 d-mail postfix/submission/smtpd[724]: disconnect from unknown[107.170.206.11]
```

I'm not sure why I can't connect from my Node.js app, but I can connect it perfectly fine on my own Macbook.

Do I need to install some certificate on my Node.js server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With port 587 you don't speak SSL directly, but start with plain text and later upgrade to SSL with the STARTTLS command. This means that `secure` must be false. See https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport.