# I've created a postfix server on my digitalocean droplet, now how do I connect via nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, postfix-mta

I have followed this guide to install postfix:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-18-04

I have successfully sent the mail using s-nail. Now how do i connect via nodemailer using nodejs? installed postfix as root, but what about the password? I dont remember creating any mail accounts using postfix.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'localhost.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
         user: '???',
         pass: '???',
    }
});
```

Comment: doesnt anybody know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting SSL error while sending email, can't connect to Postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819712/getting-ssl-error-while-sending-email-cant-connect-to-postfix)